# Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState

Tags: angular

When i try to build my app i get this error:

> Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'
>
> Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState
>
> add-new.component.html(36,31): Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'.

My HTML for check errors looks like this

```
 <mat-error>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let error of errors(addNewSiteForm.get('number'))">
         {{ errorMessages[error] }}<br />
    </ng-container>
  </mat-error>
```

And my method looks like this:

```
errors(ctrl: AbstractControl ): string[] {
        return ctrl.errors ? Object.keys(ctrl.errors) : [];
    }
```

How to fix this?

---

EDIT:

If I remove `AbstractControl`, there is no errors.
But I don't know is this good solution

Thanks.

Comment: `return ctrl && ctrl.errors ? Object.keys(ctrl.errors) : [];`

Comment: @Eliseo I still get the same errors

Comment: has you try `errors(crtl:FormControl):string[]{...}`?

Comment: yes, that was my first setting, and after first time i get this error i change `FormControl` to `AbstractControl`. If I remove AbstractControl, there is no errors. But I don't know is this good solution